# xsltproc on windows: I/O error: invalid argument if argument is absolute path

Tags: windows, xslt, mingw, mingw32, msys

I'm using **xsltproc** on Windows as per [this guide](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html)

When I run `xsltproc` with relative paths, i.e.:

```
xsltproc -o "..\output.html" "c:\templates\out.xsl" "c:\data\input.xml"
```

everything is ok.
But when I run it with absolute paths, it fails, e.g.:

```
xsltproc -o "c:\output.html" "c:\templates\out.xsl" "c:\data\input.xml"
I/O error : Invalid argument
I/O error : Invalid argument
```

tried both with forward and backward slashes as path separators, with the same result (the problem is only for the `-o` argument)

How does `xsltproc` expects a *Windows absolute path* to be encoded?

Comment: Did you try quoting the path? Like `-o "C:\output.htm"` or `-o "C:/output.htm"`? Also, what version of libxslt are you using?

Comment: I just tried with `libxslt-1.1.26.win32` and it works just fine, provided I wrap paths in quotes.  This does not appear to be a question about XSLT at all -- this is all about how to feed arguments to a Windows executable.

Comment: adding quotes makes no difference (paths have no spaces in them). this looks like a bug

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with the output file path; even though it has been double-quoted it still gave the error. As soon as I have removed the folder containing spaces it has worked. Oddly, the `%I` file fed in was in the same space-containing folder and I did not need to modify that one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that xsltproc is not aware of drive letters ("`C:\path\to\output\output.html`"). The spaces and backslashes are no problem. If I remove the drive letter from the "output" ("`\path\to\output\output.html`") everything works fine.

The problem with this "solution" is that input and output must share the drive letter.

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Have used xsltproc in both Windows and Linux environments. The Windows xsltproc processes treat some paths as Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) type. The paths to handle direct xsl and xml input files on the command line are Windows standard, but the output and internal paths must be in URI format. Not sure why the Windows version requires this and the Linux version does not, probably something when the they were compiled. For example:
Linux:
Command line XSL file path: "/path to library/parser.xsl"
Command line XML file paths: "/path to input/input.xml"
Command line --output file path: "/path to output/output.html"
Internal "document()" file path: "/path to input/input2.xml"
Windows:
Command line XSL file path: "C:\path to library\parser.xsl"
Command line XML file paths: "C:\path to input\input.xml"
Command line --output file path: "C:/path%20to%20output/output.html"
Internal "document()" file path: "C:/path%20to%20input/input2.xml"